# Bootstrapped tree values differ from PAST

Tags: r, phylogeny, r-daisy

When I compute a bootstrapped tree in R I get different values to when I use PAST (http://folk.uio.no/ohammer/past/). How can I get the output to match from the two programs?

Here's what I'm doing in R (data below):

```
library("ape")
library("phytools")
library("phangorn")
library("cluster")

# compute neighbour-joined tree
f <- function(xx) nj(daisy(xx))
nj_tree <- f(tab) 
nj_tree_root <- root(nj_tree, 1, r = TRUE)

## bootstrap
# bootstrap values do not match PAST output - why is that?

nj_tree_root_boot <- boot.phylo(nj_tree, FUN = f, tab,  rooted = TRUE)

# Are bootstrap values stable?
for (i in 1:10){
  print(boot.phylo(nj_tree, FUN = f, tab,  rooted = TRUE, quiet = TRUE))
}
# yes, they seem ok

# plot tree with bootstrap values
plot(nj_tree_root, use.edge.length = FALSE)
nodelabels(nj_tree_root_boot, adj = c(1.2, 1.2), frame = "none")
```

Typical output for the bootstrap is `[1] 100   6  39  27  23  57  53  75  71` and here's the plot (far LHS value should be 100, it was cropped somehow):

[image]

I transform the data to send it to PAST like so:

```
tab1 <- t(apply(tab, 1, as.numeric))
write.table(tab1, "tab.txt")
```

In PAST I open the tab.txt file, do multivariate -> cluster -> Neighbour Joining with Euclidian and 100 bootstrap replications, using an outgroup. From PAST I get this plot:

[image]

And the values are very different. What do I need to do with R to make the output match that from PAST? Is PAST wrong?

The data:

```
tab <- structure(list(X1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), X2 = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               X3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), X4 = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                                               2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
                                                                                                                                                   "1"), class = "factor"), X5 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                             2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               X6 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), X7 = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                               2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
                                                                                                                                                   "1"), class = "factor"), X8 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                             1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               X9 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), X10 = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
                                                                                                                                                    "1"), class = "factor"), X11 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                               1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               X12 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), X13 = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                                                 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
                                                                                                                                                     "1"), class = "factor"), X14 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               X15 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), X16 = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                                                 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
                                                                                                                                                     "1"), class = "factor"), X17 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               X18 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), X19 = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
                                                                                                                                                     "1"), class = "factor"), X20 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               X21 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), X22 = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                                                 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
                                                                                                                                                     "1"), class = "factor"), X23 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               X24 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), X25 = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
                                                                                                                                                     "1"), class = "factor"), X26 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("X1", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10", "X11", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "X12", "X13", "X14", "X15", "X16", "X17", "X18", "X19", "X20", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "X21", "X22", "X23", "X24", "X25", "X26"), row.names = c("a", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much searching around, it turn out the answer is in the `ape` package [FAQ Q14](http://ape-package.ird.fr/ape_faq.html#bootphylo):

> I have done a bootstrap analysis with boot.phylo but some bootstrap
>   values seem at the wrong place after rooting the tree. This is because
>   the bootstrap values are counted as the frequencies of clades, and not
>   as actual bipartitions. So these values are really associated to the
>   nodes, not to the edges. A consequence is that some of the bootstrap
>   values are lilely to loose their meaning after (re)rooting the tree
>   since this will affect the definition of the clades in the tree. A
>   simple solution is to include the rooting process in the definition of
>   the function FUN that is given as argument to boot.phylo. Obviously
>   the estimated tree must also be rooted in the same way before doing
>   the bootstrap. In this situation, it is more convenient to define FUN
>   beforehand. An example code would be:

```
outgroup <- 1 # may be several tips, numeric or tip labels
foo <- function(xx) root(nj(dist.dna(xx)), outgroup)
tr <- foo(X) # X is the matrix of DNA sequences
bp <- boot.phylo(tr, X, foo)
plot(tr)
nodelabels(bp) # will have "100" at the root
```

In the specific case of my question:

```
nj_tree_root_boot <- boot.phylo(nj_tree, FUN = f, tab,  rooted = TRUE)
plot(nj_tree_root, use.edge.length = FALSE)
nodelabels(nj_tree_root_boot, adj = c(1.2, 1.2), frame = "none")
```

[image]

Which matches the PAST output quite well.